# kSoap null error when attempting call()

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2

I have an issue while trying to access a method in web service, everything complies nicely, until it reaches the transport.call() line. The try/catch block fails and I get the output:

**08-25 12:38:45.380 28998-28998/com.example.nfc E/...: Error: null**

The method itself does nothing special, and does **not** take any parameters, just returns "Hello World". I tried changing it so that it does take a string and returns it, but that doesn't work either. This is my first time dealing with these kidns of things.
I had to change the url adress before posting here since it's private company information, the URL is working fine, I am sure of that.

```
String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
String URL= "http://example.com/example.asmx";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .........

    btnOdustani.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
                soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

                HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 10000);
            try
            {

                transport.call(SOAP_ACTION,soapEnvelope);
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();

                String result = response.toString();

            Toast.makeText(Podesavanja.this,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + result);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    Log.d("Error", Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
            }

        }
    });
```

Full stacktrace:

```
     08-25 13:24:55.109 30285-30285/com.example..nfc E/Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
   at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:130)
   at com.example..nfc.Podesavanja$3$override.onClick(Podesavanja.java:153)
   at com.example.nfc.Podesavanja$3$override.access$dispatch(Podesavanja.java)
   at com.example.nfc.Podesavanja$3.onClick(Podesavanja.java:0)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4832)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19844)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

Comment: Try to print the whole stacktrace and not only the message. There are exceptions that don't set the message and it is not possible to understand what happened if you don't print it

Comment: @OliveraP Plz check String URL= "http://example.com/example.asmx"; it is working or not?

Comment: I had to change the url adress since it's company information, the URL is working fine, I am sure of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem - Added an AsyncTask.
With this code added to btnOdustani.OnClickListener

```
btnOdustani.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                 AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
            try {
               String pera= task.execute().get();
                Toast.makeText(Podesavanja.this,pera,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    });
```

And then created this class:

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");

            SoapPrimitive response = null;
                try {
                    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
                    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
                    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
                    response = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
                    result1= response.toString();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
        return response.toString();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
    }

}
```